# Why First parent model reference is getting set as null when adding the same child to second parent using `ObjectBox` in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I have two objects one parent model have `ToOne` relation and a child model with `ToMany` relation back to the parent. Now if I have two parents who are setting their relation to child then the first parent's reference to child is getting null when the second parent reference is set. Also, if I remove the id field from the child then both parents child is stored in the database.

Suppose I have a class like

```
Student{
  String id;
  final teacher = ToOne<Teacher>();
}
```

and another class Teacher as

```
Teacher{
  @Unique(onConflict: ConflictStrategy.replace)
  String? id;
  @Backlink()
  final students = ToMany<Student>();
}
```

so now if I try to do something like

```
student1.teacher.target = teacher1
```

followed by

```
student2.teacher.target = teacher1
```

then if I try to check for student1 then its teacher is getting null. Why ?

Comment: Could you please give additional details what you are doing (e.g. code examples) and also detail your expectations?

Comment: @MarkusJunginger I have added an example

Comment: I tried to reproduce what you describe with your example and cannot. The `target` setter is assigning values as expected. Perhaps try including a fully reproducible example of your issue with full entities and how you're trying to access the database etc...

Comment: I found out that I was trying "insertAll" to persist in local, so when I changed it with single "insert" for each model it worked.